# Python, how I can find sum of this elements?

Tags: python, sum

Find the sum of n elements of the following row of numbers:
1, -0.5, 0.25, -0.125 ...
The number of elements (n) is entered from the keyboard.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for something like this?

```
l = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    if i%2 ==0:
        l.append(1/2**i)
    else:
        l.append(-(1/2**i))
print(sum(l))
```

Comment: What's the point of creating a list only to get the sum of its elements?

Comment: I don't think you understood, what's the point of creating a list? just save a variable as `0` and add to it on each iteration.

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
row = "1, -0.5, 0.25, -0.125, 0.5, -0.14, 0.2, -0.34"
n = int(input())
nth_sum = sum(map(float, row.split(",")[:n]))
```

Answer (score 0):

## Resolution:

You should use the formula for the sum of a geometric series, which is by far the most efficient way:

```py
n = int(input('number: '))
result = -2 * (1 - (-1/2) ** n) / (1 + 1/2) + 2
```

### Explanation:

the sum of a geometric series is defined by the formula:

[image: formula]

Where:

- `Sn` = sum of n terms
- `n` = number of terms
- `a1` = first term
- `r` = common ratio

the provided series can be thought as the alternating series with `r = -1/2` and `a1 = -2` skipping the first term. The numerator simplifies to `-2 * (1 - (-1/2) ** n)` and the denominator `(1 + 1/2)` and since we don't want the first term at the end we cancel it by adding 2 at the end `+ 2`

Answer (score -1):

```
sum([float(i) for i in input().split(', ')])
```

Assuming that the user enters a comma-separated (with a trailing space) list of numbers that can be parsed as valid floats.

Comment: the row is continuously, it means that I should enter a number like 7 and it will give me a sum of first 7 numbers in that row(1, -0.5, 0.25, -0.125, 0.0625, .... )